# Sound effect to confirm text is copied to clipboard

Tags: macos, terminal, copy-paste

How do you set a sound effect to confirm text is copied to clipboard? I am looking for my mac to make a ding whenever I copy something.

Comment: **macOS** does not, by default, have such a feature, however there are clipboard managers that can make a sound when copying and pasting. Check the **App Store** or do some googling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I only know of one Clipboard manager for macOS that has the ability to play a sound when you copy/paste:  [Copy 'Em for Mac](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/copy-em-clipboard-manager/id876540291?mt=12) ($10USD).

To be candid, when I was evaluating clipboard management tools, I didn't see many with this feature because it seems like it would get annoying very quickly.  Besides my extensive use of the clipboard which required me to look for a management tool (I settled on [FlyCut](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/flycut-clipboard-manager/id442160987?mt=12)<sup>*†*</sup>), having a sound every time something was sent to my clipboard - normally selecting and copy/cut, using the CLI tool `pbcopy` or from my password management or text expansion/replacement tools - I would imagine that my computer would sound like a telegraph operator keying out some Morse code.  You might be better served with something that gives you visual feedback rather than audible.

---

<sup>*†*</sup> [Flycut](https://github.com/TermiT/Flycut/) is an open source tool that is "free" though the developers do accept donations and I highly encourage folks to send them some compensation if you find their app/utility of use to you. I prefer to support this type development effort because their code is open for all to see.

Comment: yes, but does Flycut do what's asked here? (play sound on copy) I don't see that information on their page.

Comment: The solution I proposed @stan, was to get something with *visual* feedback rather than audible.